# Can't make Python Stockfish weaker

Tags: python, pypi, chess, python-chess, stockfish

I’ve written a chess software in Python which use Stockfish via this library:
https://pypi.org/project/stockfish/

The software works and plays well. Too well actually…

Mi idea was the app can offer a level / ELO choice, but I just can’t scale it down. It doesn’t matter if I use Stockfish or Fairy Stockfish seemingly none of the parameters has any effect, especially not the “Skill Level” or “Elo Parameter”.

I tried multiple combination it’s *only an example:*

```
params = {
        "Debug Log File": "",
        "Contempt": 0,
        "Min Split Depth": 0,
        "Threads": 2, # More threads will make the engine stronger, but should be kept at less than the number of logical processors on your computer.
        "Ponder": False,
        "Hash": 512, # Default size is 16 MB. It's recommended that you increase this value, but keep it as some power of 2. E.g., if you're fine using 2 GB of RAM, set Hash to 2048 (11th power of 2).
        "MultiPV": 1,
        "Skill Level": 1,
        "Move Overhead": 10,
        "Minimum Thinking Time": 20,
        "Slow Mover": 100,
        "UCI_Chess960": False,
        "UCI_LimitStrength": True,
        "UCI_Elo": 1000
    }

    #stockfish = Stockfish(path="/usr/games/stockfish", parameters = params)
    stockfish = Stockfish(path="/home/python/chess/fairy-stockfish_x86-64", parameters = params)
```

Comment: Try using Engine.configure or setoptions to set "Skill level".   
 Maybe it doesn't work went sent in Params? 
 https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34504/how-to-modify-stockfish-skill-with-python-chess

Comment: I use a different library as I wrote, but thanks.

Comment: If you're insinuating that *I* downvoted your question, I have in fact not voted on it in either direction.  Could you clarify how you are verifying that StockFish is not getting weaker?  Have you played a low skill level vs a high skill level?  Are you enforcing time limits for move calculations? You commented on the answer below that maybe the setting don't work on newer versions, but the official docs indicate you can set the strength by adjusting either skill level or ELO on the most current version.  The Fairy-Stockfish documentation states the lowest skill level is `-20`

Comment: "I have in fact not voted on it in either direction." OMG, I didn't think it was you, I just guessed the reason, because people in general don't like duplicated questions. But it is NOT a duplicated one.

The playing strength is very easily detectable as I have some experience with chess and also it is very is to test it against any other engine... And I did this comparison of course.

Comment: And thanks for your answer, now I tried -20 too, but nothing changed. I've to think it is an outdated library...

Comment: Pypi says the last release was July 4, 2022, so its not that out of date.  Maybe consider reporting the issue on GitHub for the project?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation(https://pypi.org/project/stockfish/) says:

> You can change them, as well as the default search depth, during your
> Stockfish class initialization:

```
stockfish = Stockfish(path="/Users/zhelyabuzhsky/Work/stockfish/stockfish-9-64", depth=18, parameters={"Threads": 2, "Minimum Thinking Time": 30})
```

i think what controlls the difficulty might be the `depth=18` parameter.

Comment: Some relevant discussion  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509966/is-the-depth-of-a-chess-engine-its-strength

Comment: I tried to change the depth (as almost anything else), but it did nothing. I have to think maybe the options works only with Stockfish 9 and not with the newer versions...

Answer (score 0):

i have played both stockfish 15.1 and 16 at very low skill levels and have beaten it or found a way to beat it. the program blunders material when the evaluation is very bad for the engine and also it makes objectively weaker moves like useless pawn moves .it is more likely to play another move altogether after it finishes analysing the correct one. its kind of fun to play an engine that makes positional errors that you must prove are errors! often you will find tactical ideas to advance your play that stock will never let you imagine at high strength.i played 15.1 on 3 and 16 on two. 15 is more human like in my opinion but will still challenge you because it usually creates good structures and is still aggressive often never connecting rooks so as to use the g file with a bishop on the long diagnal cooperating. and a wild  a or h pawn terrorizing you.if that is a common scenario for you its great practice!if it crushes you even on 2 you can go back to where you started to lose your way and try something else.usually there is some recourse available to you if the evaluation is in your favor.

Answer (score 0):

It started to work and it can play significantly weaker. I tried multiple things (like boolean variables are string), but I think key factors are:

- depth = 1
- "MultiPV": 5 (as it gives options to the Engine and on weaker levels it has a tendency to choose a weaker move)

```
params = {
        "Debug Log File": "",
        "Contempt": 0,
        "Min Split Depth": 0,
        "Threads": 2, # More threads will make the engine stronger, but should be kept at less than the number of logical processors on your computer.
        "Ponder": "false",
        "Hash": 512, # Default size is 16 MB. It's recommended that you increase this value, but keep it as some power of 2. E.g., if you're fine using 2 GB of RAM, set Hash to 2048 (11th power of 2).
        "MultiPV": 5,
        "Skill Level": 0,
        "Move Overhead": 10,
        "Minimum Thinking Time": 20,
        "Slow Mover": 100,
        "UCI_Chess960": "false",
        "UCI_LimitStrength": "false",
    }
    
    stockfish = Stockfish(path="/home/python/chess/fairy-stockfish_x86-64", depth=1, parameters = params)
```